# PDO. Подсчёт строк с параметром

Tags: php_pdo, php

Как правильно составить запрос, если мне надо узнать кол-во строк в таблице с определённым параметром? Пытался так:

> SELECT count(`id`) FROM `items` WHERE subcategory = :subcategory

Но в ответ получаю:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':subcategory' at line 1

**UPD**

```
try { 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$sets['hostname'].'; 
    dbname='.$sets['name'], $sets['user'], $sets['password']); 
    $db->query('SET NAMES utf8'); 
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
    $db_rows = $db->query('SELECT count(id) AS count FROM items WHERE subcategory = :subcategory'); 
    $db_rows->bindParam(':subcategory', $manifest_array[1]['name']); 
    $sth->execute(); 
    $db_rows->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $rows = $db_rows->fetch(); 
    $rows = $rows['count']; 
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: Приведите код на PHP (желательно, поменьше).

Comment: А что это может значить? `subcategory = :subcategory` Кто такой `:subcategory`

Comment: @alexlz, это `placeholder`.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вместо `query` использовать `prepare`/`execute`. Кстати, ваш `$sth` не определён.

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(id) AS count FROM items WHERE subcategory = :subcategory';
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':subcategory', $manifest_array[1]['name']);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: именно, 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то rowCount() то, что вам нужно. Правда в версиях до 5.1.6 эта няшность не работает с SELECT